# Можно ли использовать один и тот же DataGridView1 в нескольких вкладках tabControl и как это реализовать?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть приложение на C# VisualStudio можно ли использовать один и тот же DataGridView в нескольких вкладках tabControl и как это реализовать?

Comment: Вместо ненужного тега `visual-studio` укажите, пожалуйста,  `WinForms` или `WPF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повесь на TabControl обработку событий. Со старой вкладки будешь убирать dataGridView1, а в активируемую добавлять.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.Selected += tabControl1_Selected;
        tabControl1.Deselected += tabControl1_Deselected;           
    }

    public void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TabPage.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
    }

    public void tabControl1_Deselected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TabPage.Controls.Remove(dataGridView1);
    }
}
```

Или добавить в дизайнере:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
  // ...
  this.tabControl1.Selected += new TabControlEventHandler(this.tabControl1_Selected);
  this.tabControl1.Deselected += new TabControlEventHandler(this.tabControl1_Deselected);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: 1. Только не нужно делать подписку на события и в дизайнере, и вручную в коде. Достаточно чего-то одного. Иначе событие будет происходить дважды. 2. `Remove` делать не обязательно, достаточно `Add` - у контрола не может быть двух родителей, поэтому он автоматически удалится у предыдущего. 3. Хорошо бы почистить пример: уберите ненужный `Form_Load`.

Comment: Спасибо, внёс изменения.

Answer (score 0):

Пример Сергея вполне рабочий, однако, приведу ещё два способа.

1.

Можно разместить `DataGridView` не на `TabControl`, а на самой форме, поверх табконтрола. При этом никаких обработчиков событий не надо и не будет мелькания грида при переключении вкладок.

Для этого в режиме дизайнера нужно перетащить его на пустое место формы (таким образом, родителем станет именно форма). Потом в свойствах датагрида вручную задать нужные координаты, сдвинув его на `TabControl`. При этом может оказаться, что грид будет ниже в z-ордере и его не будет видно. Тогда нужно нажать кнопку Bring to Front на тулбаре.

Если создаём контролы вручную, то вместо строки

```
// помещаем датагрид на табконтрол
tabControl.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(dataGridView);
```

нужно написать

```
// помещаем датагрид на форму
this.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
// задаём такие координаты, чтобы он был в нужном месте табконтрола
dataGridView.Top = 50;
dataGridView.Left = 20;
// выводим его поверх других контролов
dataGridView.BringToFront();
```

2.

На каждую вкладку помещаем свой собственный компонент `DataGridView`. И все их привязываем к одному и тому же источнику данных. Элементарно! Теперь можно редактировать данные на любой вкладке, а при переключении на другую, они будут автоматически обновлены благодаря биндингу.

То есть, в коде будет что-то вроде:

```
tabControl.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
tabControl.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(dataGridView2);

dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
dataGridView2.DataSource = source;
```

Пожалуй, этот способ самый правильный.